# why ('1' == 1) evaluates to False?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I couldn't understand this thing that if python just converts expressions on both sides of == to a particular type why is this not equal to True

Comment: "python just converts expressions on both sides of == to a particular type" - it does not

Comment: But Python *doesn't* convert the expressions to any particular type.  Strings do not, in general, represent any sort of number, so they are considered inherently unequal to any numeric type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're testing if a string is equal to an integer, which it never can be. Python doesn't convert the values on both sides of == to the same type. `1 == 1` would return True and `"1" == "1"` would return True, but the string, "1", is not equal to the integer, 1.

Answer (score 0):

Because they are not comparable types. If you put a number in quotation marks it becomes a string. This basically means that it is being treated as letter or set of letters rather than a number that can have math done on it. So what the expression is really asking is whether the letter 1 is the same as the number 1. And while they may look the same to a human the program sees them as being completely different.

the == operator does not convert anything, its more like a function that looks at two inputs, checks if they are the same and returns a boolean (true or false).

If you want to compare a string and an integer in python then you need to perform a conversion on one or both of them by telling the program what to convert it to:

```
var1 = 132
var2 = "132"

print(str(var1) == str(var2))
print(int(var1) == int(var2))
print(var1 == var2)
```

will give back

```
true
true
false
```

`str()` tells the interpreter to treat the variable like a string whereas `int()` tells it to treat it like a number.

```
print(str(var1)+str(var2))
print(int(var1)+int(var2))
```

will give back 123123 and 246 respectively.

Answer (score 0):

In python thing inside **' '** or **" "** are considered as a string. So for condition if('1' == 1) returns a false.
But python has got type conversion where **if(int('1') == 1)** will return true.

Answer (score 0):

In Python, `==` is considered an equality operator whereas `=` is considered an assignment operator. In the example you provided, Python is not converting the expressions on each side of the operator to a particular data type. Rather, it is assessing whether the symbols or values on each side of the operator are equal. Given that `'1'` is considered a string and `1` is considered an integer, the expression you provided will return False. If you were to utilize casting to ensure the values on each side of the operator were the same data type, then the expression would return True. For instance, both `int('1') == 1` and `'1' == str(1)` will return True.